# Git hosted on my server + client

Tags: git, repository, client

I'm new to git. I created a repo on my server. So I have : http://mysubdomainforgit.mydomain.com/example.git

I downloaded Versions for Mac and now I would like to connect to my git. But I don't know what to fill for location (they say something like svn+ssh://host/location).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Comment: Linux Debian 2.6.35 (on MediaTemple gridserver)

Comment: 'svn+ssh://host/location' is certainly wrong for a Git repo. If you have SSH access to your server try 'ssh://host/location', see also `man git-cone`, section 'GIT URLS'.

Comment: [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) is only for SVN repositories. If you're looking for a Mac git client, check out [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/), [GitBox](http://gitboxapp.com/), or [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) for a start. (Though personally, I prefer using git from the command line.)

Comment: Ok, I'm trying GitBox. But my hosting service tell me that I have to fill : ssh://serveradmin%example.com@example.com/home/00000/domains/git.example.com/html/example.git        But GitBox doesn't like serveradmin% .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://iantearle.com/blog/media-temple-subversion-tutorial) points out:

> For example, if your site were example.com, you would connect as follows:

```
ssh serveradmin@example.com@example.com
```

> The domain "`example.com`" is in there twice:
>
> - first because it’s part of your full username, and
> - second to point SSH at the right server.
>
> (If your SSH client complains about not being able to connect, you can try replacing the first `@` sign with its encoded version, “`%25`″.)

So, in your case, you could try:

```
ssh://serveradmin%25example.com@example.com/home/00000/domains/git.example.com/htm‌​l/example.git
```